# Django liking system suggestions?

Tags: django

I'm doing a social networking app, in which users can will posts and 'like' them. My current liking system works like this:

- Every post has a **models.CharField** called *user_vote* wil a max_length of 65596
- When a user presses 'like' button (If the post wasn't liked before), their user_id will be added to *user_vote* (string appending) like this:

  ```
  story.user_vote += str(current_user) + ' '
  ```
- The system check that if the user's id is already in the post's *user_vote* by splitting *user_vote* string into a list and check if the user's id is already there:

  ```
  voted = str(current_user) in story.user_vote.split()
  if story and voted == False:
      points = story.points + 1
      story.points = points # Add points
      story.user_vote += str(current_user) + ' '
      story.save()
  ```

The system works fine, but I think it's not so well-designed.
Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm.  I think that `Like` model with FKs to `Story` and `User` will be the cleaner design:

```
class Like(models.Model):

    story = models.ForeignKey(Story)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('story', 'user', )
```

So liking code will be just:

```
Like.objects.get_or_create(story=story, user=user)
story.points = story.like_set.all().count()
story.save()
```

And at any time you will able to get the list of stories liked by the user:

```
Story.objects.filter(like__user=user)
```

Or list of users who liked the story:

```
User.objects.filter(like__story=story)
```

You can even have additional info in the `Like` model.  For example the time when the story was liked by the user:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Like(models.Model):
    ...
    liked_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**UPDATE**: As alternative you can use M2M field in the `Story` model:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    ...
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

This option have the same advantages as the `Like` model.

The only thing is lack of additional info for the like. It can be done with the [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) property but then you code will look exactly as with the `Like` model :-)

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying that. But how do I register it to admin.py?

Comment: @ArchManiac you can edit `Like` model as the inline of the `Story` admin: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: @ArchManiac and look at the update of my answer.  `M2M` field will be available in the `Story` admin. For easier editing you can add the `liked_by` field to the `filter_horizontal` property of the `StoryAdmin`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal

Comment: Any way to verify if the user has already liked a post?
I'm gonna use it on the template.

Comment: `like = Like.objects.filter(story=story, user=request.user).first()`.  If `like` is not `None` then user is already liked the story.

Comment: Yeah I've done that. But I had a hard time trying to pass it to the index template, since my liking request is ajax. I have no idea.

Comment: Then return this data in the JSON response: `{'already_liked': like is not None}`

Comment: Oh gosh. I'm serious. You taught me A LOT today. Thank you again.